# Get real base URL

Tags: php

You can get a base URL with `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]`, but sometimes if you have different projects in the same website, you need to save them in different directories. For example, if you have `/var/www/myproject/`, the real base URL is `http://yourhost.com/myproject/`.

If you try with `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] + $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`, it gives the full request URL, and the problem becomes worse when you use friendly URLs. For example, if you use it in something like `http://yourhost.com/myproject/controller/action/` you can't get the real base URL (`yourhost.com/myproject`).

How can I get the real base URL in these situations?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing something like that?

Comment: String splits? Seems like the easiest way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you may need this..

```
$uri = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? strip_tags($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) : '';
$urlvariables = (substr($uri, 0, 1) == '/') ? substr($uri, 1) : $uri;
$variables = explode('/', $uri);
echo $whatyouneed = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $variables['1'];
```

You may give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Define it. If you have any sort of global project configuration at all (you should), you can set it up there. That’s more or less how CodeIgniter (for example) does it.

```
define('BASE_URL', '/myproject/'); # Include the host name if you truly must
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate it, put this code in your project root:

```
define('BASE_PATH', str_replace('\\', '/', __DIR__));
define('BASE_URL', preg_replace('|/+|', '/', strtolower(preg_replace('|^'.str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])).'|i', '', BASE_PATH))));
```